# accountsd process uses all CPU - AMSAccountStoreCache error

Tags: catalina, cpu

the process `accountsd` is using more than 300 % of my CPU. The error messages in the console that appear are:

- `AMSAccountStoreCache: [AF547297] An ACAccountStore has no associated media type. Returning the default media type for the current process. accountStore = AMSAccountStoreCache | defaultMediaType = com.apple.AppleMediaServices.accountmediatype.itunes`
- `"Cannot check access to a private account type: com.apple.account.AppleAccount"`

What I already tried from other questions:

- Remove Mail accounts
- Remove calendar accounts
- Stop Spotlight from indexing your HDD
- Kill AppleSpell and delete Spelling folder

Still the same error. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to remove the whole keychain and restart without any help.
Now the following error appears as well in the console: `ACAccount: [9CB59699] Failed to decrypt an account property. key = accountFlags | value = {
} | value.class = __NSDictionary0`

The last new things I did on the mac was installing PyCharm and WebStorm but it already ran for about 2-3 days

Comment: I did the latest update and now it is working again.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried some things, like removing keychain with a UUID name, but that did not work. For me signing out of iCloud account solved the 300% CPU of accountsd.